# Intel Graphics driver (Graphics Update Tool 2.0.3) on Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: apt, intel-graphics, 16.10, ubuntu-gnome

I have downloaded and installed **Intel Graphics Update Tool v2.0.3** on my **Ubuntu GNOME 16.10** (from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.3)). Then I tried to launch it and got error:

```
"**NO_PUBKEY 611B903CAB97EA77**" during resource "https://download.01.org
/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main yakkety" check. Driver installation aborts.
```

How can I solve that problem, where can I get this missing public key ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)